# GridView scroll in scaled view not working

Tags: android, android-gridview

To have effect of zoom in gridView I have scale it with 2.0f value.
Scaling (zoom effect) on that grid view works fine.

As the view is zoomed I want to have a horizontal and vertical scroll in this view.

Comment: put it in a scrollview (except you are not supposed to put gridviews in scrollviews)

Answer (score 0):

Please write code in grid Xml code:

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: 2 definitions of the same attribute doesn't compile, btw.